# Make a ... of himself

Tags: phrases

A quote by Dr. Johnson goes

> "*He who makes a beast of himself gets rid of the pain of being a man.*"

The phrase "*make a beast of himself*" appears to have the definition of "*to behave like a beast*", in the same way as how "*make a ... of himself*" would function in the idiom "*make a fool of himself*".

Here is my question: is it appropriate to use the expression "make a ... of himself" be used in all cases to mean "*to behave like a ...*"? (e.g. He makes a coward of himself.)

Comment: I don't suppose "making a statue of himself" would involve behaving like a statue.

Comment: Yes, the phrase "makes a ___ of himself" is another way to say "he behaves like a ____" - just be aware that there are some usages are more idiomatic than others, for example: "...makes an ass of himself", "...makes a pest of himself", "...makes a nuisance of himself", and your example, "...makes a fool of himself"

Comment: @njd it could. I've seen plenty of street performers do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily - I can think of the phrase 'make a laughingstock of oneself' which does not precisely mean to behave like a laughingstock (because there is no such creature with specified behaviors), but rather to turn oneself into the object of ridicule.